# Answer preview and final formatting differ in the face of cross-paragraph inline HTML tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

There is a minor bug in formatting preview feature.  In the following case, preview shows all text striked out (even text *following* the `</s>`), but final formatting doesn't allow cross-paragraph HTML tags.

Example: I guess could try this:

```
bla bla bla</s>
```

The above example is not completely fictional.  In some cases it is useful to strike out obviously invalid part of an answer, but not delete it since it provides vital context for the comments or following parts of the answer.

*[There seem to be several bug reports for preview/final formatting inconsistencies, but I didn't find anything about this case]*

EDIT:

There is `<s>` tag after "Example: " text, but final markdown formatting doesn't show it.

Answer (score 2):

Your closing `</s>` is in a code block – so it's not actually a closing tag. Striking through several paragraphs works just fine:

```
<s>first

second

third</s>
```

turns into

> <s>first</s>
>
> second
>
> third

as expected. But since your opening `<s>` tag is never closed, you actually have invalid HTML (which does indeed get handled differently by the client-side and server-side renderer).

---

**Edit:** After a recent change, the client- and server-side handling of these cases are closer to each other, so after the next build, the preview and the final version of your example will look identical.

Of course you should still not rely on deliberately invalid markup doing the correct thing; but in most cases, you'll now be made aware of problems in the preview already, not just in the final rendering.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no expectation of *intentionally* valid markup producing consistent results.